# Is program account size resizable

Tags: solana-program, rust

Understand that Solana now can resize the PDA account size, but is it currently possible to resize the program size itself? I have written a program and have deployed it to mainnet, and since then I've added a lot more code into it, and am running into program account not big enough issue. Wonder if anyone has run into this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will be soon possible to resize the program data using `UpgradeableLoaderInstruction::ExtendProgramData` but the feature is currently behind the feature flag.

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/19475

And the feature flag pull request

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/26386